# Helm upgrade through Jenkins pipeline not working

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, kubernetes-helm

I am using helm upgrade command to upgrade my helm charts on EKS cluster through Jenkins CI/CD pipeline. When there is a change in helm chart the upgrade is working properly, deploying a new pod in the namespace.

But, when there is a change only in Docker image which is stored in Elastic Container Registry, the pipeline run successfully, but the changes are not present.
In addition, here is the command which I am using in the pipeline for helm upgrade

`sh "helm upgrade --install --namespace ${NAMESPACE} --values ${HELM_VALUES} --version ${CHART_VERSION} ${RELEASE_NAME} ${CHART_NAME}"`

Chart Version is in format 1.0.${env.BUILD_NUMBER}.
The imagePullPolicy is set to Always. If you need any additional information, please comment on the post.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Helm upgrade will only upgrade the pods if there were any changes.
The image pull policy set to always is great, but are you changing the image tag?
You can trigger the upgrade by:
Changing manifest data like deployment resources, or use the image tag to deploy the pods, when using a changeable image tag like git commit hash etc.
If nothing is changed then the upgrade will succeed but not deploy anything new.